# how to check a value in data base if exist or not

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm trying to check if the database has a specific value from a specific column 
this is my Function

```
 public boolean Check(String num) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RECORD + " WHERE "
            + KEY_NUM + "= '" + num + "'",null);
    if (c == null) {
        // doesn't exists therefore insert record.
        return false;

    } else
        return true;
}
```

but the result is always true ! even the value which i input is not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cursor is not null, thats why you're always in the {return true} path - `db.rawQuery` returns a new cursor instance.

Android provides a method `Cursor.getCount()` see here in the documentation [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29).

```
public boolean Check(String num) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RECORD + " WHERE "
            + KEY_NUM + "= '" + num + "'",null);

    // Let's ask the cursor how many rows are fetched
    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        // doesn't exists therefore insert record.
 // we have no result
        return false;

    } else
// there is min. 1 row
        return true;
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer , you just attention me about that , it really works